# Is a closed convex subset of a Hilbert space with empty interior necessarily thin?

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let's say that a subset $C$ of a real Hilbert space $H$ is *thin* if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a hyperplane $M$ such that $C$ is contained in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $M$. Equivalently, $C$ is thin if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a unit-norm linear functional $f$ on $H$ such that $\operatorname{diam} f(C)<\epsilon$.

Suppose $C\subset H$ is closed, convex, and has empty interior. Does it follow that $C$ is thin?

#### Remarks

- Such $C$ need not be *contained* in a hyperplane: the [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube#The_Hilbert_cube_as_a_metric_space) is an example.
- Every compact subset of $H$ is thin, but $C$ need not be compact: e.g., it could be a hyperplane itself.
- It's necessary to assume that $C$ is closed; otherwise, $\ell^1 \subset \ell^2$ (or any other dense subspace) would be a counterexample.
- The same question could be posed in other normed spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think here is a counterexample: the non-negative cone in $L_2[0,1]$
$$
C=\{x\in L_2\colon x\ge 0\text{ a.e.}\}.
$$
Clearly, it is a closed convex set with an empty interior.

On the other hand, $L_2=C-C$ since any $x\in L_2$ can be split as $x=x_+-x_-$ where
$$
x_+=\max\{x,0\},\quad x_-=\max\{-x,0\}
$$
are the positive resp. negative part of the function $x$. If $|f(C)|\le\epsilon$ then
$$
|f(L_2)|\le |f(C)|+|f(C)|\le 2\epsilon<1
$$
for small enough $\epsilon$, which contradicts the unity norm assumption on $f$.

Comment: Oh... and the same example works in the sequence space $\ell^2$. And you don't need small $\epsilon$, since $f(L_2)$ has to be all of $\mathbb R$ for any nonconstant $f$... a nonconstant functional cannot be uniformly bounded on the space.

Comment: @Gerry My first reaction was that in $\ell^2$ the interior of the non-negative cone is not empty, but you are right, it works since $x_n\to 0$.